# Why does this class show up as "undefined" only on SOME executions?

Tags: javascript

I have an input element class in one document:

inputClass.js:

```
function inputField(name) {
    this.elem = document.getElementsByName(name);
    this.type = this.elem[0].type;
    this.name = name;
    this.label = this.labelCheck();

    inputField.getVal = function () {
      switch (this.type) {
        case "checkbox":
        case "radio":
          return ;
      }
    };
  }
```

When I create an instance in the main script, it works, but on some executions I get this:

```
ReferenceError: inputField is not defined
var user = new inputField('user');
```

It'll work, but if I refresh once or twice, I get that Reference error. Then I refresh again and it's fine. How can this be explained?

Comment: Make sure the instance is created after loading the `inputClass.js` file.

Comment: First of all, this isn't a class but a contructor function. In second place, how are you loading this script?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="inputClass.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="formValidate.js">`

The file with the _constructor_ function(thank you Matias) is loaded first.

Comment: i think here `inputField.getVal = function ()` should be `this.getVal = function ()`